# Gitlab Yaml Setup Example for Flask and MySQL

Tags: mysql, flask, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have setup a simple flask project to create an API for testing the CI/CD feature of Gitlab. I locally started connecting to an MYSQL Database via Xampp Apache Server and all my test work fine. Now I want to adjust the .gitlab-ci.yml such that the CI creates a mysql database, creates database and table, such that the CI runs the pytests for every commit. Can anyone help me with this?

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - Static Analysis
  - Test

pylint:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
    - pylint

pytest:
  stage: Test
  script:
    - pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that has worked well for me is to run a mysql server somewhere that my runner(s) can reach, and then during a pipeline create the schema and run migrations.

For this example, assume we have a mysql server installed and running at `qa-database.example.com`:

```
stages:
  - database_setup

Setup QA Database:
  stage: database_setup
  image: mysql:latest
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - mysql -h qa-database.example.com -u ci_user -pci_password -e "create database example_${CI_PIPELINE_ID};"
    - bash run_migrations.sh
```

The `GIT_STRATEGY` variable tells Gitlab CI not to checkout the codebase for this step since it isn't needed and would waste a few seconds.

After this, you can update your app's config to point to the new schema, and run your tests, deploy, etc. In lower environments, I set my schema names to something like `my_db_${CI_PIPELINE_ID}`. In prod, it would just be `my_db`, but appending the pipeline ID allows me to have multiple apps running with their own schemas so they don't overwrite each other.